# CSS is removed after server response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement some thing like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1/) in my menu.

***Code:***

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a class="menu" href="page1#">About MHG</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="page2#">Workout Programs</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="page3#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="page4#">Contact Us</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu" href="page5#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
</ul>

$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

I have `<a>` tags in my page but on clicking these tags request goes to server side and my `CSS` is lost when my page loads after server response, this is for the obvious reason that a new page is loaded.

***Question***

Is there any alternate to this situation that `CSS` that I have applied just after selecting `<a>` tag still remains after server response?

Comment: are you using a server side language?

Comment: try to change href="page#" to href="#page"

Comment: If you want to do it via jquery then you have to load pages via ajax or alternatively set in every page class for it

Comment: @Cristian href is whole link like `/domain/pages/action.do?action=someMethod&repSubMenu=parameter#page`

Comment: thanks @EhsanSajjad that will do here, but I can not use `AJAX` in my case.

Comment: You'll need to use you java to add the class on the html itself when the new page loads (which means you'll need an identifier set in java for each page).  Not used java before so I wouldn't know how this is done

Comment: You could also set the correct class with server-side logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the event being triggered.

```
$('a.menu').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

### Update

**Based on updates to the question**

The easiest way to solve this is with CSS.  A common way is to have a class on the `body` that represents the page you are on.  Then you can set CSS based on that.

**Example**

About page:

```
<body class="about">
    <ul>
        <a class="about-link>About</a>
    <ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.about .about-link {
    color: red;
}
```

You can then have css for each page and it will only target the correct link.

Comment: @ColinBacon this will not solve my problem, as Ehsan Sajjad said.

Answer (score 0):

You should check which page is being served and then give its a class accordingly. There are several ways of doing this in JAVA depending on the pattern you are using and if you are using [Scriplets](http://www.jsptut.com/Scriptlets.jsp) or [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/get-started.html).

At it's simplest, you get the URI of the page you are on:

```
<% String thisPage = request.getRequestURI();%>
```

... and test against it when building your nav. If they match then add the class:

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a class="menu <% if(thisPage.equals("/page1.jsp")){out.println("active");}%>" href="/page1.jsp">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu <% if(thisPage.equals("/page2.jsp")){out.println("active");}%>" href="/page2.jsp">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu <% if(thisPage.equals("/page3.jsp")){out.println("active");}%>" href="/page3.jsp">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```